# Angularjs - clean field input text and select

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I need to find the equivalent form in angular to do the next code jquery:

```
$("#form1 :input[type=text]").prop("value", '');
$("#form1 select").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
```

Any idea?

Thanks for the help. Best Regards.

Comment: Angular and Jquery are not very good combination .. it wont be feasible & developer Friendly ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html form

```
<div ng-controller="formController">
      <form>
         <input type="text" ng-model="input"/>
         <select ng-model="select">
           <option value="1">pick a value</option>
             ...
         </select>
        <button ng-click="clearForm()">Clear</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Angular controller and module

```
angular.module('FormModule' , [])
.controller('formController' , function($scope){
 $scope.input = '';
 $scope.select = '';
 $scope.clearForm = function(){
  $scope.input = '';
  $scope.select = '';
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add model to input and select:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="input"/>
<select ng-model="select">
  <option value="1">pick a value</option>
  ...
</select>
```

and then in controller use:

```
$scope.input = '';
```

and

```
$scope.select = "1";
```